What are the unitaries of an irrational rotation algebra?
I have the following (please correct me if I have read it wrong.)
Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. The corresponding irrational rotation algebra is the universal $C^*$-algebra generated by unitaries $u,v$ such that $vu=\exp{(2\pi i\alpha)} uv$.
I'm trying to de-abstract $u,v$ and make them concrete.  What domain are they in and what do they look like?  Can you exhibit them, for example if $\alpha=1-\log_2(3)$?  I've done a good bit of reading but I can't get a foothold on the many abstract concepts used to define them.

Let $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) \otimes L^2(\mathbb{T})$. Then $v$ can be given by $v(\delta_n \otimes f) = \delta_{n+1} \otimes f$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$. $u$ is then given by $u(\delta_n \otimes f) = \delta_n \otimes \exp(-2n\pi ia)zf$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, and where $z: \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{T}$ indicates the identity function.
The reason this is the irrational rotation algebra is because the above is the standard representation of $C(\mathbb{T}) \rtimes_{\gamma, r} \mathbb{Z}$ of the reduced crossed product, where $\gamma$ is the action given by rotation by $2\pi a$. The irrational rotation algebra is, basically by definition, the full crossed product $C(\mathbb{T}) \rtimes_\gamma \mathbb{Z}$. But as $\mathbb{Z}$ is amenable, the reduced and full crossed products coincide.
For a reference on the topic of $C^\ast$-algebra crossed products, see Chapter 4 of Brown and Ozawa’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations”.

Thanks. What domain is $v$ in?  You may have underestimated my ineptitude.

@RobertFrost Both $u$ and $v$ are unitaries acting on the Hilbert space $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) \otimes L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Thanks David. I don't know if a unitary is a real or complex number, a matrix or vector of real numbers, a function on the real numbers, a function from one domain to another or something more abstract altogether... I'm trying to make the unitaries concrete or in other words see one rather than the name or definition of one.

@RobertFrost Unitaries are surjective linear functions from a Hilbert space to itself that preserve the inner products. In this specific case, the definition of $u$ and $v$ are explicitly written down. I honestly don’t know how you can be more concrete than this. I mean, if I say I want to “see” a ring and make it “concrete”, but I don’t know the definition of it, wouldn’t you just tell me the definition of rings and write down an example of a ring by stating what it is as a set and what the ring operations on it are as functions?

@RobertFrost But if you don’t even know the definition of unitaries, asking about irrational rotation algebras is a quite bad idea. It might be better to first learn the definitions and ask for more basic examples of operators on Hilbert spaces.

What domain are $u,v$ in, for the irrational rotation algebra for $\alpha=1-\log_2(3)$? That is the question which it is the best idea for me to ask right now.

@RobertFrost The exact same Hilbert space. There isn’t any thing to gain by choosing a specific $\alpha$. The definition of $v$ doesn’t even change between different $\alpha$.

@RobertFrost Perhaps you should clarify what you even meant by “domain”. As I said, unitaries are linear maps between Hilbert spaces. By domain, I just assume you want to know which Hilbert space the said unitary acts on. But given your lack of knowledge regarding what unitaries even are, perhaps you have some different meaning in mind.

@RobertFrost By the way, irrational rotation algebras cannot be represented on finite-dimensional spaces, so if you want me to write down some nice matrices for $u$ and $v$, that is not possible. Technically, you could choose a basis and write down infinite matrices for them. But those are just going to be even less instructive than the definitions I wrote down.

Thank-you David that has helped. So I think it's an infinite-dimensional matrix over $\Bbb R$

@RobertFrost Over $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. I don’t think it’s really a particularly helpful way to think of unitaries, but I suppose you can see it that way if it helps your understanding.

Thanks. P.S. it was also helpful to learn that really you are using the properties of the matrices without reference to the specific entries within them - but personally I need to know what an object is in order to visualise it. It's not just algebra to me.

@RobertFrost I understand that, though I should warn you that if you want (or need) to delve deeper into Hilbert spaces, operator theory, $C^\ast$-algebras, and such, getting used to not seeing explicit matrices is a necessity. While any operator can theoretically be written as a (possibly infinite) matrix, explicitly calculating the matrix entries is generally speaking impossible, or at least overly cumbersome and not exactly informative either. Basically no one will actually write down those matrices for these reasons.
